# Calculate sum column filtering identical values on X number of columns

Tags: r, group-by, filtering, calculated-columns

I'm trying to calculate a sum column where the sum is calculated for each row from rows that have identical values in X number of columns.

In the example I want to sum values from each row (from value column to result column) if at least 2 values in columns S1, S2 or S3 are identical to values in the row being calculated. For row 1 values would be summed from rows 1, 2, 3 and 5.

```
S1 <- c(1,1,1,0,1,0)
S2 <- c(1,1,1,0,0,0)
S3 <- c(1,0,0,0,1,1)
value <- c(9,5,3,2,4,1)
result <- c(21,17,17,3,14,7)
df <- data.frame(S1,S2,S3,value,result)
df

  S1 S2 S3 value result
1  1  1  1     9     21
2  1  1  0     5     17
3  1  1  0     3     17
4  0  0  0     2      3
5  1  0  1     4     14
6  0  0  1     1      7
```

I couldn't get group_by to work if all conditions don't match. I'm looking for a solution that can be used for larger amount of rows and columns.

This question is related to my previous question where sum was calculated if all columns matched.

[Calculate sum column filtering identical values on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75554823/calculate-sum-column-filtering-identical-values-on-multiple-columns/75559068#75559068)

Edit: typos.

Comment: Can you show the logic of getting 14

Comment: Sorry, I had copied wrong values to the latter table. Row 5 has at least 2 matching values with rows 1, 5 and 6 so result is 9+4+1=14.

Comment: If it is atleast 2, then 6th row had 2 0s where as 5th had 2 1s.  How is it matching

Comment: I guess I have multiple conditions (values in columns S1, S2, S3 match values for that row) and I would like to sum values from rows where number of true conditions is >= X. I'm how this could be calculated or if there is an easier way.

Comment: 5th and 6th rows match/are identical in columns S2 and S3 (at least 2 columns)

Comment: Probably, you want a `rollup` or `cube` from `data.table` i.e. `cube(as.data.table(df), j = sum(value), by = c("S1","S2","S3"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing each S1:S3 row sequentially with all S1:S3 rows and applying the conditional check.

```
cbind(df, result = sapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) 
  sum(df$value[colSums(unlist(df[x,1:3]) == t(as.matrix(df[,1:3]))) >= 2])))
  S1 S2 S3 value result
1  1  1  1     9     21
2  1  1  0     5     17
3  1  1  0     3     17
4  0  0  0     2      3
5  1  0  1     4     14
6  0  0  1     1      7
```

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(S1 = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0), S2 = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0), S3 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), value = c(9, 5, 3, 2, 4, 1)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```